# Installing MySQL Client 5.6 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql-connector, mysql-cli

I have a legacy project that I'm trying to modernize, and part of that involves setting up a more efficient system of automated backups using `mysqldump`.

The app's database is using MySQL 5.6, and is hosted via an RDS instance. To get `mysqldump` up and running, I believe I need to install a version of `mysql-client` that corresponds to 5.6.

However, running `apt-get install mysql-client` installs 8.0 by default. However, I can't find any version-specific versions of `mysql-client` available. Running `sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.7` returns a notice that there's no installation candidate available.

Is it still possible to install older versions of `mysql-client`? If not, is there another way to get ahold of the `mysqldump` functionality?

**Edit:** As @exussum noted below, 8.0 is backwards compatible with 5.6 and 5.7. I was hitting errors when running `mysqldump`, which I'd assumed indicated incompatibility, but were actually related to my app specifically.

Comment: According to [Ubuntu Package Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mysql-client&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), 18.04 has 5.7. You shouldn't be getting 8.0 as the default version and "`no installation candidate`" error for MySQL Client 5.7. Do you have security repository enabled? What is the output of `apt-cache policy mysql-client` and `grep -R "security" /etc/apt/sources.list*`? Moreover, software installation questions specific to Ubuntu are better suitable for [ubuntu.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are backwards compatible, so you can use mysql-client 8 to dump mysql-server 5.5

to get a specific version docker is great

(`sudo apt install docker`) to install

`docker run mysql:5.6 mysqldump`

will run mysqldump though docker, and you can choose your version there easily enough